# Model Binding Not Working Correctly -- Razor Pages, C#

Tags: c#, html, razor-pages

The select populates correctly, but when I submit and the post method is triggered, the model property "dataIWant" is not updated... Any suggestions?

index.html:

```
         <div class="input-field col s12">
            <select name="dataIWant">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose data I want...</option>
                @foreach(var t in Model.cTypes)
                {   
                    <option value=@t.ToString()>@t.ToString()</option>

                }
            </select>
            <label>Data Selector</label>
        </div>
```

index.html.cs:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public string dataIWant { get; set; }
```

Let me know if any additional information is required. I'm leaving out the bulk of both files because they don't seem to be relevant based on examples I am seeing online. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was logging the value incorrectly in the post method. This does work.